# What size of wire should be used for a 60A Tesla Wall Connector?

Tags: wiring, 240v

I am in the process of installing a 240v Tesla wall connector on a 60 Amp breaker to draw max 48 amp. Distance from panel to site is approximately 110 feet.

I want to go with a cable that has 3 conductors + ground. What size and type of wire would you recommend? NJ resident.

Comment: 4ga AL in conduit is probably your least expensive option.   But agreed with @SolarMike get a better electrician.

Comment: Is the site a garage, or just a wall connector on a post outside?

Comment: What do the instructions call for?

Comment: The instructions probably don't specify wire size. They'll call for a particular circuit capacity.

Answer (score 5):

Your distance is short enough that voltage drop won't matter.  Normal wire sizes can be used.

NEC 110.3(B) requires you follow the *paper* instructions which are UL-Listed as part of the device's UL listing.  The Gen 3 Wall connector's  [instructions are here](https://www.tesla.com/sites/default/files/support/charging/Gen3_WallConnector_Installation_Manual.pdf).

See page 20-21 esp. note bottom of page 20.  **There is no need for 3-wire+ground cable**.  The only reasons to want neutral are

- You want to feed a sub panel to power other loads there, *which actually would be rather elegant; I recommend it*.  Note this is mandatory if this is an **out**building and there is already 240V power there, because you can't have 2 circuits or feeders of the same voltage to the same outbuilding.
- You have 3-phase power (not likely outside NYC) AND want to power 2-3 Wall Connectors *independently*.

Unrelated: If you have any thoughts toward a second EV, **brief yourself on Wall Connector Power Sharing**, manual Page 23. My understanding is this feature is active now.

Since you didn't specify indoor or outdoor, I can't specify a cable or wire type (unless you run conduit).

*Prices will reflect normality, not crazy COVID pricing (which seems to have about doubled cable prices)*.

### Most versatile choice, $1.50/foot + $70 once

Since you specified a costly 3-wire (w/ neutral) feeder for some reason, *you might as well get full bang for your buck* and feed a sub panel.

That will allow you to consolidate all other loads in this area to this sub panel - which I remind you *is legally required* if this is an outbuilding!  If there is an existing sub panel and it has enough spaces, just enlarge its feeder.  Otherwise hey -- panels are *cheap*.  Unfortunately most people chintz out on panel spaces, so most subpanels are full. I don't fool around, I think 24-30 spaces is a fine panel size for a garage. **Spaces are *cheap***.

So now it's just down to wires.  One of the nice thing about subpanels is they have lugs appropriate for aluminum wire (*made of* aluminum actually).  So that lets us run aluminum feeder, which saves a fortune.

- #2 feeder is 90A (typ. $1.50/foot)
- #1 feeder is 100A (typ. $2.00/ft)
- #1/0 feeder is 120A (typ. $2.50/foot)
- #2/0 feeder is 135A (typ. $3/foot)

So figure out what combined ampacity you would want and run that. Aluminum is cheap, and perfectly safe in heavy feeder applications like this.

### Forget the sub panel, $1.20/foot + $40 once

You can also run aluminum *without a sub panel, just to the Tesla Wall Connector*.  For this your minimum size is #4 aluminum (65A). You would need to use three Polaris connectors to "pigtail" the aluminum wire to copper wire, since in a glaring oversight, Tesla failed to make their Wall Connector lugs compatible with aluminum.  I guess they figure you're buying an $80,000 car...

### Cost is no object, and I prefer copper: $4/foot

If you want to run copper direct, and you can **avoid** using NM or UF type cables, then you can run #6 copper (65A at 75C thermal, which NM and UF are not allowed).  Expect $4/foot.

This can run direct to the Wall Connector's terminals.

If you want to do the sub panel as in option #1, and use copper feeder, well, it's wasted on the sub-panel's aluminum lugs (AL lugs are the universal donor, playing well with Cu). But if you really want to, take the sizes above, subtract 2 numerical sizes (#2 becomes #4) and triple the price LOL.

### Cost is no object and I really want NM: $6/foot

If you insist on using NM type cable, *which is only legal indoors*, then you can run #4 NM copper (70A @ 60C thermal). Expect $6/foot under normal conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My plan was to feed a sub panel but I decided against.  Instead I went with two 4 awg thhn wires with 10 ground inside a 1" ENT conduit (within drywall ceiling) and 1" pvc40 (exterior drywall inside garage). What do you think?

Comment: @Mike I would say that's fine if aluminum.  If copper, if you ever want a sub panel there you have the headroom for both the EVSE and other loads too.  Just add a neutral wire and you're all set.

Answer (score 3):

You have to size for the breaker, not the expected load. The consensus tends to be #4 Cu or #2 Al for a 60A breaker. You can also put #6 THHN in conduit to increase the heat rating, and therefore the current capacity. However, if you expect to every own a newer vehicle that can pull more current, or if you may ever have two chargers, plan for that.

You're not at a length that would require upsizing due to voltage drop.